# MVC 4 Code First ForeignKeyAttribute on property ... on type ... is not valid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I keep getting this error and I do not know why.

The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'Ward' on type 'BioSheet.Models.BioSheetModel' is not valid. The foreign key name 'WardId' was not found on the dependent type 'BioSheet.Models.BioSheetModel'. The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names.

```
public class Ward
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AddressId")]
    [Required]
    public virtual Address WardAddress { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BioSheetId")]
    public virtual List<BioSheetModel> BioSheets { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Code { get; set; }
}

public class BioSheetModel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    public String Email { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("WardId")]
    [Required]
    public Ward Ward { get; set; }

    public String CellPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public String HouseNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String DoB { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public String OtherInformation { get; set; }
    public String PreviousCallings { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TimePeriodId")]
    public virtual TimePeriod TimePeriods { get; set; }
    public String HomeWard { get; set; }
    public Boolean OkToText { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Required]
    public DateTime TodaysDate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EMPId")]
    public virtual EDUEMP EduEmp { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SingId")]
    public virtual Sing Singing { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MissionId")]
    public virtual Mission MissionIn { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone help me resolve this?

Comment: see this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824232/cant-get-property-names-working-with-foreign-keys-in-code-first/40525460#40525460

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`[ForeignKey("WardId")]` indicates that the property to use as a foreign key to the Ward table should be the `WardId` property on the `BioSheetModel` class.

You're getting the error because you haven't defined a `WardId` property on the `BioSheetModel` class.

Add

```
public int WardId {get; set;}
```

for a non-nullable/required relationship, or

```
public int? WardId {get; set;}
```

for a nullable/optional relationship.

Comment: You could also omit the `[ForeignKey]` attribute entirely and make your `Ward` property `virtual`, which will allow Code First to generate the foreign key relationship itself (It will generate a foreign key column in the database called `Ward_Id` or something similar).