# Entity Framework code first one-to-zero relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-5

I am trying to do a one-to-zero relationship between the table staff and department.

```
public class Staff
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    // other fields

    [ForeignKey("DepartmentID")]
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Staff Staff{ get; set; }
}
```

When I run this code, it gives this error:

> The property 'DepartmentID' cannot be configured as a navigation property. The property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter. For collection properties the type must implement ICollection where T is a valid entity type.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884526/mvc-4-code-first-foreignkeyattribute-on-property-on-type-is-not-valid

Comment: It's not helpful since I already declared the foreign key property in the class.

Comment: Read the answer, you are using the `ForeignKeyAttribute` wrong. Add it to the navigation property instead of the integer.

Comment: Can you please show me the correct way of doing this. Because I couldn't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

change your model like this ,now you can use DepartmentID as foreign key

```
public class Department
{
    [Key]
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Staff Staff{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It didn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Staff
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    // other fields    

    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DepartmentID")]
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

Since your [naming is correct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx), I think you can also try to remove the `ForeignKeyAttribute`. For more info see: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx